# Looping filling textboxes and clicking buttons in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem in js (or jQuery).
I managed to fill and click button on page by script:

```
 document.getElementsByName('code')[0].value='ads0mx0';
  document.getElementsByName('event')[0].click();
```

and now the page accepts the code and i want to add another code after it refreshes.

So my script fills textbox and clicks button for me and page submits (refreshes). I want js to fill the same textbox and again click button after it reloads.

Thanks for the help :)

EDIT: To clarify code is input of type = text and event is input of type = submit.

Comment: please clarify what u actually want to do in details. your question needs more information.

Comment: what is `code` and `event`??? What type of tag are they???

Comment: Code is input of type = text and event is input of type = submit.

Comment: Then u dont basically need to reload, do u???
You can simply do this using JavaScript to append another `textbox` each time you click on **add** button.

Comment: If it is necessary to reload then u have to use some SESSION variable to check how many textbox were there and to add another textbox. this process is tiresome.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in a function and call it in onload event of body. like:

html:

```
<body onload="performAction()">
```

js:

```
function performAction(){
document.getElementsByName('code')[0].value='ads0mx0';
  document.getElementsByName('event')[0].click();
}
```

EDIT:

try `window.onload()` function:

```
window.onload = performAction()
```

Comment: It's a script for site i don't have permission to change html I think. I just wanna automate process.

Comment: is your site support jquery?

Comment: Yes. I have input text on it and a submit button. And I have to insert for example 100 codes, one at a time. Everytime I click Submit button it reloads. I want to automate process.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I tried in javascript console in Chrome.

Comment: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:

Comment: I don't see any changes. I think the site is reseting js or something because when I try with tamperscript addon, the values of variables reset every time it submits. What can I do about it?